# TypeError: $(...).jqxTree is not a function

Tags: jquery, json, jqxwidgets, jxtree

i am Trying To Bind the tree But Getting TypeError. Json Values Not Binding in jqwidgets tree.I just add The Plugin in Head Tag And declare it.

myCode :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jtree/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jtree/jqxcore.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jtree/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jtree/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jtree/jqxpanel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jtree/jqxtree.js"></script>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     LoadOrgUnitData();
});

function LoadOrgUnitData() {                        
                var source = [
            { label: "Item 1", expanded: true, items: [
                { label: "Item 1.1" },
                { label: "Item 1.2", selected: true }
            ]
            },
            { label: "Item 2" },
            { label: "Item 3" },
            { label: "Item 4", items: [
                { label: "Item 4.1" },
                { label: "Item 4.2" }
            ]
            },
            { label: "Item 5" },
            { label: "Item 6" },
            { label: "Item 7" }
        ];
    // Create jqxTree.
                alert(source);

                $('#jqxTree').jqxTree({ source: source, height: '300px', width: '300px' });             
}
```

[image]

Comment: yes! I also don't see the method in your provided code.

Comment: C-link This method in jqxtree.js Please Take a look http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxtree/jquery-tree-getting-started.htm

Comment: You can also check whether the path to the files is correct and whether these are all the required files.

Comment: @scripto Jquery Conflict Happens Now Its Worked i just Removed the version jquery-1.10.1.min.js and add jquery-1.10.2.min.js